# Request Units in Cosmos DB in Free Tier

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The Azure Cosmos DB states that for the first 12 months, 400 RU/s and 5GB of storage is free. Also, it states that the minimum RU/s for purchase is 400.

Does that mean minimum RU/s for each Collection? Like if I create 2 collections, would I have to purchase minimum 800 RU/s (400x2)?

Or does it mean I can distribute the RU/s purchased by me, among all my collections?

Comment: Yes, RU's are per collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean minimum RU/s for each Collection? Like if I create 2
>   collections, would I have to purchase minimum 800 RU/s (400x2)?

Yes, the minimum RU/s limitation is for each collection. When you create collection on the portal, you could see the two situations: Fixed & Unlimited.If you create 2 collections(Fixed),you need to purchase minimum 800 Ru/s.

[image]

> Or does it mean I can distribute the RU/s purchased by me, among all
>   my collections?

No, you can't distribute the RU/s purchased by yourself among all your collections. Actually , you could check the price details as below from this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/).

> With Azure Cosmos DB, you only pay for provisioned throughput and data
>   stored in a container (e.g., a container of documents or a table of
>   records or a graph consisting of vertices/edges). Provisoned
>   throughput, billed as Request Units (RU) per second or (RU/s), allows
>   you to read from or write data into containers. Each container is
>   billed on an hourly basis for throughput provisioned in increments of
>   100 RU/second, with a minimum of 400 RU/second, and data stored (in
>   GBs). Unlimited containers have a minimum of 100 RU/s per partition.

Considering the cost, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) to adjust your throughput settings based on your actual situation.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because of the way how data partitions are working:

- Fixed size collection gets one partition.
- One partition is 10 GB at maximum.

When you select the UNLIMITED collection, depending on how many RUs you selected, there will be different count of partition prepared for your collection.

The count of partition is probably something like RUs/5000.
Therefore you're actually paying not really for throughput, not really for collections, but the main thing here is the count of **partitions**.

Every collection has at least one partition, that's why you're forced to pay so much even for very small collections.

```
1  col, 400 ru/s    10 GB     = 1 partition
1  col, 11 000 ru/s 10 GB     = you're forced to move to unlimited plan = 2 part.
1  col, 100 000 ru  100 GB    = 10 partitions 
10 col, 400 ru each 1 GB each = 10 partitions
```

And there is also the business point of view, where this is really unsuitable for projects with many small collections. I had a chat with MS employee, here is what I think is relevant:

Azure Cosmos DB is a globally distributed, horizontally scalable, multi-model database service. As a database system designed for the cloud, Cosmos DB exploits the three properties which are central to the cloud: (1) global distribution (2) elastic scalability and (3) multi-tenancy (and the cost efficiencies resulting from it). Customers can elastically scale throughput and storage of an Azure Cosmos DB container (e.g., a table/graph/collection of documents) across any number of geographical regions and get guaranteed low latency and high availability. Azure Cosmos DB is the first globally distributed database service in the market today to offer comprehensive SLAs encompassing throughput, latency, availability, and consistency. Azure Cosmos DB has a write optimized, resource governed, schema-agnostic database engine capable of natively supporting multiple data models (key-value, documents, graphs and column-family) and a multitude of APIs for data access (e.g., MongoDB, Cassandra, SQL (Cosmos DB), Gremlin, Azure Table storage and more APIs to come) natively, efficiently and in an extensible manner.

With respect to pricing model, we are working on a number of things based on customer feedback:

### 1 - Lower the price of entry for a container

In December, we’ve announced 60% cheaper entry point for unlimited collections/containers. In February of 2017, we lowered the entry point for unlimited containers by 75%. By continuously making improvements in our service and we able to further lower the entry price for unlimited containers by making it 60% cheaper than before. Instead of provisioning 2,500 RU/sec as a minimum, you can now provision an unlimited collection at 1,000 RU/sec and scale in increments of 100 RU/sec. Unlimited containers (collections) enable you to dynamically scale your provisioning from as low as 1,000 RU/sec to millions of RU/sec with no limit on storage consumption.

### 2 - Allow customers to “pool” their provisioned throughput at the database level

**(“multi-collection RU sharing”)**

Allow customers to provision across multiple collections (at the database level) and pool all of the provisioned throughput This in-turn will allow the customers to share their throughput at the database level easily.

### 3 - We provide a free tier

One of the most common requests from developers using Cosmos DB was the lack of a “free tier”.

At Ignite in September, we announced a free tier with 12 month access to all popular services in Azure. As a part of free tier specifically for Cosmos DB you get 5GB in storage and 400RUs.

### 4 - We provide Try Cosmos DB for free experience

There is Try Azure Cosmos DB for free experience which gives you a time-limited experience (currently 7 days) with Cosmos DB.

It is designed for trying out Cosmos DB, doing a tutorial, a demo, doing a quick start, a lab without requiring an Azure account or a credit card.

(1), (3), (4) are already available and (2) will be coming later in H1 CY2018.

**UPDATE 5 / 2018**
Microsoft just changed the rules, so you can pool the provisioning throughout the collections inside one database. (Point 2. above)

Long story short, since 5/2018 you can share your RUs per all your collections inside one DB.